# Downloading with a progress bar from another class

Tags: c#, event-handling, download

I'm creating a class for downloading a file. I found a snippet from WebClient which does the same but has only 1 class (main class). **Is it possible to write a class that can attach an event to a control from the main class in such a way that all they need is to set up the Download Class then it'll just attach itself from whatever is assigned to it?**

I believe there's a better way than invoking a thread loop the progress variable from the class.

Example :

```
public partial class Main : Window
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void reportProgress() {
    Class1 cls1 = new Class1();
    // Some thread invoking here
    while (true)
        progressBar1.Value = cls1.progressValue;
    }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int progressValue = 0;
    public void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressValue.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

*WebClient Snippet (only in the main class therefore you can attach it to a control directly) :*

```
private void DownloadFile()
    {
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);

            try
            {
                // Start downloading the file
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://website.com/file.exe"),
                    "filename.exe",
                    "E:\\");
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                throw new WebException(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading can be in another class, but you need to add some code for WebClient in Window code-behind.

```
class Downloader
{
    internal WebClient Client { get; set; }

    internal Downloader() {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Client = client;
    }

    internal void DownloadFile( string uri, string path ) {
        using ( Client ) {
            Client.DownloadFileAsync( new Uri(uri), path );
        }
    }
}
```

In window code-behind you need to get the `Client`, and hook events. That's all.